# I want to monitor wildfly 9.0.1 (heap used , non heap used etc)through zabbix 3.0.2,

Tags: wildfly, zabbix

I want to monitor wildfly 9.0.1 (heap used , non heap used etc) from zabbix 3.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my simple app that will give you a clue how to fetch such information. https://github.com/stankay/zabbix-jboss-probe

Steps:

1. Make the app running against your instance of Wildfly
2. Prepare Zabbix probe that will use this app to fetch necessary numbers (currently only heap/nonheap supported)

Michal